getting error to fetch the data in getter method
error is coming:

LWC1535: Unexpected plugin compilation error: Plugin - lwc, Hook - transform, Cause - Invalid expression {isInvoiceExpanded(invoice.key)}

JS Code
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getInvoiceTreeMap from '@salesforce/apex/InvoiceTreeController.getInvoiceTreeMap';

const CHUNK_SIZE = 10;

export default class InvoiceTreeComponent extends LightningElement {
    invoiceTree;
    expandedInvoiceKey;
    error;
    loadedItemsCount = [];
    

    @wire(getInvoiceTreeMap)
    wiredInvoiceTree({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.invoiceTree = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ key: key, lineItems: data[key] }));
            console.log('data for invoice---->',data);
            console.log('this.invoiceTree---->', this.invoiceTree);
            // this.invoiceTree = this.invoiceTree.map(item => ({ key: item.key, lineItems: data[item.key] }));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.invoiceTree = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleInvoiceClick(event) {
        const clickedInvoiceKey = event.currentTarget.dataset.invoiceKey;
        console.log('clickedInvoiceKey-->',clickedInvoiceKey);
        this.loadedItemsCount[clickedInvoiceKey] = CHUNK_SIZE; // Load the first chunk of Invoice Line Items
            console.log('loadedItemsCount-->',this.loadedItemsCount);
            console.log('novie',this.isInvoiceExpanded(invoiceKey));


         if (this.expandedInvoiceKey === clickedInvoiceKey) {
            this.expandedInvoiceKey = null; // Collapse the clicked invoice if already expanded
        } else {
            this.expandedInvoiceKey = clickedInvoiceKey; // Expand the clicked invoice
            this.loadedItemsCount[clickedInvoiceKey] = CHUNK_SIZE; // Load the first chunk of Invoice Line Items
            console.log('loadedItemsCount-->',this.loadedItemsCount);
        }
    }

    handleViewMore(event) {
        const invoiceKey = event.currentTarget.dataset.invoiceKey;
        console.log('invoiceKey',invoiceKey);
        this.loadedItemsCount[invoiceKey] += CHUNK_SIZE; // Load the next chunk of Invoice Line Items
        console.log('More click',this.loadedItemsCount);
    }

    get isInvoiceExpanded() {
        return (invoiceKey) => this.expandedInvoiceKey === invoiceKey;
    }

    get visibleInvoiceLineItems() {
        return (invoiceKey) => this.invoiceTree.find(item => item.key === invoiceKey).lineItems.slice(0, this.loadedItemsCount[invoiceKey]);
    }

    get remainingInvoiceLineItemsCount() {
        return (invoiceKey) => Math.max(this.invoiceTree.find(item => item.key === invoiceKey).lineItems.length - this.loadedItemsCount[invoiceKey], 0);
    }
}

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Invoice Tree Structure">
        <template if:true={invoiceTree}>
            <ol>
                <template for:each={invoiceTree} for:item="invoice">
                    <li key={invoice.key}>
                        <div class="invoice-header" onclick={handleInvoiceClick} data-invoice-key={invoice.key}>
                            {invoice.key}
                        </div>
                        **<template if:true={isInvoiceExpanded(invoice.key)}>
                            <ol>
                                <template for:each={visibleInvoiceLineItems(invoice.key)} for:item="lineItem">
                                    <li key={lineItem.Id}>{lineItem.Name}</li>
                                </template>
                            </ol>
                            <template if:true={remainingInvoiceLineItemsCount(invoice.key)}>
                                <div class="view-more" onclick={handleViewMore} data-invoice-key={invoice.key}>View More ({remainingInvoiceLineItemsCount(invoice.key)})</div>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ol>
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            <p>{error}</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>


<template if:true={isInvoiceExpanded(invoice.key)}>

Is not allowed in LWC. You must have an already-computed property.
<template lwc:if={invoice.isExpanded)}>

You'll need to find the appropriate element in memory to set the property on.
Note that if:true is deprecated. Use lwc:if instead.

There is no code with your error message. I assume the error is on the line.
console.log('novie',this.isInvoiceExpanded(invoiceKey));
invoiceKey is not defined anywhere and it's causing the error.

LWC1535: Unexpected plugin compilation error: Plugin - lwc, Hook - transform, Cause - Invalid expression {isInvoiceExpanded(invoice.key)} - LWC1060: Template expression doesn't allow CallExpression (10:35)

if condtion for using getter -  

yes, you can't pass parameters into properties in HTML

put computed values into the array and it'll solve the issue

yes but getting error unexpected Plugin so give me the solution how to pass the value

Could you please share the one snipped of code so its very helpfull



this forum is not for providing solutions, but for helping to fix the issues and point into the right direction
